# Is there an FM radio app for the iPhone?

Tags: software-recommendation, iphone

I am planning to buy an iPhone, but the one thing missing is FM radio.

Is there a way to listen to FM radio on the iPhone?

Comment: Vist http://appadvice.com/appguides/show/am-fm-radios for a list of apps on the iPhone which can recieve FM radio

Comment: Yes, everyone seems to say use the [radio app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunein-radio-pro/id319295332?mt=8), but isnt the point that you have to pay for the download in an app where fm radio is free. I also like the random programing news/ music of the fm station I listen to. Sometimes I dont want to make up my own playlists. Thats the point of radio a bit of random input.

Answer (score 4):

There's no good public answer for this question. There is an FM radio in the iPod Nano, but leaving it out of the iPhone is clearly a design decision. There may have been issues with chip suppliers, but I suspect that had Apple wanted to have an FM radio in the device, those issues would have been dealt with.

It's somewhat more likely that Apple sees FM radio versus material it sells or rents via the iTunes Store as a zero-sum game. Consuming more of the former makes it somewhat less likely that the latter will be purchased.

Given the famous Apple disdain for focus groups and market research, it's probably most likely that someone in an iPhone design meeting said "Hey, who listens to FM radio?" and got no reply, so that feature was cut

Answer (score 1):

I realize your question is for a broadcast FM radio app but why not get your radio content through streaming? I use three excellent apps for streaming radio content on both iPhone and iPad:

Pandora for music: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pandora-radio/id284035177?mt=8

TuneIn radio for NPR and other talk: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunein-radio-pro/id319295332?mt=8

You can also get NPR news broadcasts through their NPR news app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/npr-news/id324906251?mt=8